# LinkedIn API Message Post not showing up in feed

Tags: c#, uwp, linkedin-api

I'm using the Microsoft.Tookit.Services in a uwp C# app. I already have twitter and facebook working but I dont see my linkedin message in the feed during testing. I'm using the information found here:

http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/services/Linkedin/

Although I am getting a success message, I do not see the post. 
Does anyone have any experience with this that can help me?

```
await LinkedInService.Instance.ShareActivityAsync(MessageTextBox.Text,LinkedInShareVisibility.Anyone);
```

Comment: Does your url that LinkedIn can scrape preview information?

Comment: Whether I post a url or text it doesnt show up

Comment: Have you check the response that get from the `ShareActivityAsync` method? It will return the `LinkedInShareResponse` class, you should be able to test the Url from the `UpdateUrl`.  Please also try the official sample of the [Linkedin](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/LinkedIn%20Service).

Comment: This is has been resolved. It seemed to be an issue on LinkedIn's side.

Comment: @Brizzler I am facing the same issue. Can you share the solution, please?